# Extracting data from Excel using VBScript

Tags: excel, vbscript

I have a requirement to extract legacy data from spreadsheets and load/convert to csv,DB. While I know this can be done with Python and other backend scripts, the data is highly critical and want to make sure there is no loss with date formatting etc. So, decided to keep the implementation at source and dabbling in vb script.

The problem is, the sheet from which I am trying to extract has multiple tables.
For example:

```
            ColA   ColB   Col C   ColD
Row1        Date   Group1 Group2 Group 3
Row2       Jan-13  25     26      27
Row3       Jan 18  35     29      19
Row4                      20      15
<empty row>
       Y/Y %  YTD %  Group %
        15      20     40
```

From the above data set, I only need to extract data from ColA to Col(N) which is varying and only until it hits the empty row. Extracting the entire spreadsheet is pretty straightforward.

```
Dim myExcel
Set myExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

Dim myBook
Set myBook = myExcel.Workbooks.Open(src_file)

myBook.Sheets(WScript.Arguments.Item(0)).Select
```

Any help on how I can extending this for extracting only the specific set of columns and rows?

Thanks so much in advance,
Bee

Comment: From your sample code, I think you should be specifying VBA in your title and tag, not VBScript. They are 2 very different things.

Comment: It sounds like you have 'islands' of data; look at the [Range.CurrentRegion property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196678.aspx).

Comment: `CurrentRegion` is the same as hitting CTRL+A with a given cell selected.  On first press, it will select all of the contiguous data.  This can be tricked if the empty row is not actually empty.  It also forms a block which will include empty cells (like `A4` and `B4` above).  If CTRL+A selects the data you want, then you are off and running.  Be aware that going through CSV in the middle can be dangerous with dates.  If you can go straight into a DB, you will be much better off.  That also saves the hassle of exporting only a single block of cells to CSV.

Comment: Thank you all for your replies and sorry if I didn't mention in my original post that I'm looking at doing this directly from the backend without opening the spreadsheet. So I guess VBScript is correct and not VBA?